# Pandas dataframe slicing and manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have dataframe `df1` as follows

```
+------+----------+-----+
| Date | Location | Key |
+------+----------+-----+
|      | a        |   1 |
|      | a        |   2 |
|      | b        |   3 |
|      | b        |   3 |
|      | b        |   3 |
|      | c        |   4 |
|      | c        |   4 |
|      | b        |   5 |
|      | b        |   6 |
|      | d        |   7 |
|      | b        |   8 |
|      | b        |   8 |
|      | b        |   8 |
|      | b        |   9 |
+------+----------+-----+
```

and `df2` below is sliced from that.

```
+------+----------+-----+
| Date | Location | Key |
+------+----------+-----+
|      | b        |   3 |
|      | b        |   3 |
|      | b        |   3 |
|      | b        |   5 |
|      | b        |   6 |
|      | b        |   8 |
|      | b        |   8 |
|      | b        |   9 |
|      | b        |   9 |
+------+----------+-----+
```

The goal is to find the time difference between the `Key` changes in `df2`(like from the last 3 to 5, 5 to 6, 6 to the first 8, last 8 to first 9 and so on), add them up, repeat this for every `Location` item and average them.

Can this process be vectorized or we need to slice the dataframe for every machine and manually compute the average?

[EDIT]:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1142-b85a122735aa>", line 1, in <module>
    s = temp.groupby('SSCM_ Location').apply(lambda x: x[x['Key'].diff().ne(0)]['Execution Date'].diff().mean())

  File "C:\Users\dbhadra\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 930, in apply
    return self._python_apply_general(f)

  File "C:\Users\dbhadra\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 936, in _python_apply_general
    self.axis)

  File "C:\Users\dbhadra\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2273, in apply
    res = f(group)

  File "<ipython-input-1142-b85a122735aa>", line 1, in <lambda>
    s = temp.groupby('SSCM_ Location').apply(lambda x: x[x['Key'].diff().ne(0)]['Execution Date'].diff().mean())

  File "C:\Users\dbhadra\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1995, in diff
    result = algorithms.diff(com._values_from_object(self), periods)

  File "C:\Users\dbhadra\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 1823, in diff
    out_arr[res_indexer] = arr[res_indexer] - arr[lag_indexer]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try do with

```
g=df.groupby(['Location','Key'])
(g.first()-g.last().groupby('Location').shift()).mean(level=0)
```

Comment: Is that on df1 or df2? Ideally, should be df1. df2 is really an intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

`s = df.groupby('Location').apply(lambda x: x[x['Key'].diff().ne(0)]['Date'].diff().mean())`

Is this what you mean? It averages the time delta of date when the key value changes per location. If you meant the average of change of 'Key' just change 'Date' to 'Key'.

Comment: Please specify which df you mean, df1 or df2

Comment: This also gives TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: df1, and your error is because either your key or you date columns are strings (whichever one you tried). Use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` to change your date column to the datetime64[ns] , or`df['key'] = df['key'].astype('int')` to change your key column to int.

Comment: I changed to datetime but still I get a traceback. See EDIT.

Comment: please check ```df1.dtypes``` and tell me the output.

Comment: Location: object, Date: datetime64pns], Key: int32

Comment: I'm not sure how else to help you, the error is on the diff() with strings. diff is called on both the Date and Key column. As long as they are datetime64[ns] and int it should fine. So you must be doing something else to it to change the dtype before you call my code, or not changing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# obviously we will group by Location
groups = df1.groupby('Location')

# we record the changes and mark the unchanged with nan
df1['changes'] = groups.Key.diff().replace({0:np.nan})

# average the changes by location
# ignore all the nan's (unchanges)
groups.changes.mean()
```

Output:

```
Location
a    1.0
b    1.5
c    NaN
d    NaN
Name: changes, dtype: float64
```